# Error compiling OpenCV 3.0.0 into raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, recipe

```
CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/floodfill.cpp.o: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/build.make:1353: recipe for target 'lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0.0' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0.0] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2378: recipe for target 'modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:137: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Hi all, im trying to compile openCV3.0.0 but i keep getting recipe for target all failed, error 2. Already tried various solutions found online but no avail and I cant seem to understand the error that I am getting.

Does anyone know how I can solve this  error? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can carefully reinstall Raspbian and follow this [guide](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/26/how-to-install-opencv-3-on-raspbian-jessie/).

Answer (score -2):

I don't know how to solve the error, but I have a compiled file for Python 3.4,  [download it](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9p9eaqtvuzkdo5l/cv2.so?dl=0) and put it in the directory /use/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages, import it in terminal, it should work.